# Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /data/1/5/59/145/5222471/user/6267807/htdocs/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 708

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting the following error code and cannot add any post types, cannot activate/deactivate plugins from the Wordpress editor (I can do this from FTP be renaming plugins), cannot add new users.

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in
>   /htdocs/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 708

Wordpress version 5.2.2 (just updated - I think this might have happened when I updated)
PHP 7

Line 708 in my post.php is:

```
$post->post_content = (string) apply_filters( 'default_content', $post_content, $post );
```

Things I've tried:

- Deactivating all plugins and reactivating one at a time
- Switching to the default theme
- Checking the tables through PHP My Admin (they all came back ok)

I expect to be able to add posts.

Comment: You have initialize the `$post` variable before you can set its properties.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Jerodev! I am waiting on a database increase and then will try implementing this.